# TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'dict'>

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I am trying to train my model on my local GPU and it gives an error while the same code runs properly on Google Colab.

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("tglcourse/lsun_church_train", cache_dir='dataset')

image_size = 256
channels = 3
batch_size = 1

from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# define image transformations (e.g. using torchvision)
transform = Compose([
            # transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            Resize(image_size),
            CenterCrop(image_size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Lambda(lambda t: (t * 2) - 1)
])

# define function
def transforms(examples):
   examples["pixel_values"] = [transform(image) for image in examples["image"]]
   del examples["image"]

   return examples

transformed_dataset = dataset.with_transform(transforms).remove_columns("label")

# create dataloader
dataloader = DataLoader(transformed_dataset["train"], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# print(type(dataloader))
batch = next(iter(dataloader))
```

It gives the error on the last line `batch = next(iter(dataloader))`

It says

```
TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'dict'>
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "diff_lsun_church.py", line 486, in <module>
    batch = next(iter(dataloader))
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 2166, in __getitem__
    key,
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 2151, in _getitem
    pa_subtable, key, formatter=formatter, format_columns=format_columns, output_all_columns=output_all_columns
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py", line 532, in format_table
    return formatter(pa_table, query_type=query_type)
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py", line 281, in __call__
    return self.format_row(pa_table)
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py", line 387, in format_row
    formatted_batch = self.format_batch(pa_table)
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py", line 418, in format_batch
    return self.transform(batch)
  File "diff_lsun_church.py", line 475, in transforms
    examples["pixel_values"] = [transform(image) for image in examples["image"]]
  File "diff_lsun_church.py", line 475, in <listcomp>
    examples["pixel_values"] = [transform(image) for image in examples["image"]]
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 61, in __call__
    img = t(img)
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 304, in forward
    return F.resize(img, self.size, self.interpolation, self.max_size, self.antialias)
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 419, in resize
    return F_pil.resize(img, size=size, interpolation=pil_interpolation, max_size=max_size)
  File "/home1/rishi_suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional_pil.py", line 233, in resize
    raise TypeError('img should be PIL Image. Got {}'.format(type(img)))
TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: I really don't believe that it throws that error. If it does, you need to show the full traceback.

Comment: Hi. I have updated the full traceback. Would be great if you could have a look.

Comment: What do you get if you use `x, batch = next(iter(dataloader))`?

Comment: I get the same error even then

Comment: You should update Python version.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Does not solve the issue